# Debian live-build won't generate binary-hybrid.iso after first run

Tags: debian, debian-squeeze

My computer:

- Debian Squeeze amd64
- `live-build` package is version 2.0.12-2 (newest in Squeeze)

I'm trying to build a Debian Live CD with some custom files and whatnot. Here's what I did:

```
$ mkdir debianlive
$ cd debianlive
$ lb config
[output omitted]
# lb build
[output omitted]
$ ls -AF
auto/    cache/   config/  binary-hybrid.iso  binary.packages
binary/  chroot/  .stage/  binary.list
```

But then, say, I add something to config/chroot_local-includes/, and I want to rebuild the iso. So I run `# lb build` again, and this time, it skips updating `binary-hybrid.iso`. Specifically, it outputs

```
 [...]
 P: Begin building binary iso image...
 W: skipping binary_iso
 [...]
```

So is there any quick and easy way to get live-build to rebuild the iso? Am I missing something obvious?

Things I've tried:

- Delete `binary-hybrid.iso` and hope live-build recreates it. Does **not** work.
- Delete the `.stage` directory. This **works**, but it's not optimal since `# lb build`'s config stage then has to re-extract and re-install EVERY SINGLE PACKAGE.
- Use live-build version 3.0~a45-1 from Sid. Works about the same as 2.0.12-2. Does **not** fix my problem.
- Run `$ sudo lb binary iso`, because the manpage claims that's the specific step performed to build the iso. Does **not** work.

Comment: I recommend you try the version in Debian Unstable (in a chroot/VM of course) and see if you can reproduce this behavior. If so, file this as a bug. Another alternative is to ask on the development mailing list.

Comment: @Tshepang Will do. I was just hoping it was a simple fix (which apparently it's not).

Comment: @Tshepang I was successful in setting up a chroot, installing live-build version 3.0~a45-1, and getting it to build an iso the **first** time, and the iso booted fine in a VM. Same problem, though—live-build doesn't under any circumstances modify or recreate the iso after that unless I delete the `.stage` directory or start over completely.

Comment: I'm going to post the output of every single step. Maybe that'll help.

Comment: On second thought, no I'm not. I'll figure out some other way to make a livecd.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you set `BINARY_IMAGES=iso-hybrid`. By default (in Ubuntu at least) `lb` does not produce an ISO, only a squashfs and the bootloader.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Then I remembered I should have used the `lb` clean with the `--binary` option. I renamed auto directory to _auto to avoid the scripts inside it for a moment. Otherwise it runs the default lb clean which deletes the whole chroot directory.

Then I ran the following commands as root:

```
chroot ./chroot
apt-get install packages_that_i_want_to_add
exit
lb clean --binary (this removes the previous iso or img image but keeps chroot dir)
lb build ( first rename your _auto directory to auto, if you have any.)
```

Also, if you cannot access internet during `chroot apt-get`, replace your `/etc/resolv.conf` with the one in your main Linux.